# CSS multiple divs inside of container makes page extend out of height 100%

Tags: html, css, height

I`m googling, coding but can`t find a solution for my problem. I have container set to 100% height which contains another 100% container and also two divs with fixed height and that messes up the whole idea of having all the content in one screen with no need to scroll.
https://jsfiddle.net/6jk91tnq/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're under the impression that `height: 100%` means *fill the space*, however it means "Set the height to 100% of its parent container".

In your example, you have two container divs with 100% height. The one on the outside has 100% height of its parent (body). The inside container has 100% height of its parent, which is the previous container - in essence you have an inside div that you're telling "match the height of the entire page".

**If you want something to stick to the bottom of a page** (and disregard all other elements), you can take it out of the flow and forcefully position it using `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

The outside container should be the only one with 100% the child div should be less than that

```
<div style="height:100%">
<div style="height:90%;"/*or any value <100%, that is appropriate for your design */></div>
<div>
```

This means that the outer div is going to be the screen size, and the inner div is going to be 90% of whatever the parent div is,

If you would write something like this

```
 <div style="height:50%">
<div style="height:100%"></div>
<div>
```

The container div would only cover half of the page but the inner div will cover all the height of the outer div, which 100% of its parent size.

By this i mean you should lower the height size of the first child div to achieve a one pager in your fiddle,